# Power BI DAX : Get sum of a column based on another

Tags: grouping, powerbi, dax

Let say I have the folowwing table :

```
Client    Sales
A         1000
A         100
A         10
B         1000
B         10
C         1
```

I would like to add another column Names TotalClient at the end which would the new table look like this :

```
Client    Sales   Total
A         1000    1110
A         100     1110
A         10      1110
B         1000    1010
B         10      1010
C         1       1
```

Is this possible either in DAX or in the query editor ? I tried many ways, but still can't figure out how.

I was able to get information I needed using the SUMMARIZE function to get another table, but I run into other problem in term of security. It seems the data table gets filtered right, but not the summarized version.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to know how to use `CALCULATE` to adjust your filter context.

```
Total = CALCULATE( SUM( Table1[Sales] ), ALLEXCEPT( Table1, Table1[Client] ) )
```

This says to calculate the sum of the sales for all rows in the table where we've removed any row context except for the client. Thus you get the sum over all rows where the client matches the client in the current row.

---

If you only have these columns, you can do this

```
Total = CALCULATE( SUM( Table1[Sales] ), ALL( Table1[Sales] ) )
```

This removes only the `Sales` row context and leaves the `Client` row context. This probably will not work as expected if you have other columns as well since they will still be part of the row context.

---

You can also remove all filter context with `ALL` and then explicitly add back in the filtering you want:

```
Total =
CALCULATE(
    SUM( Table1[Sales] ),
    ALL( Table1 ),
    Table1[Client] = EARLIER( Table1[Client] )
)
```

or do similarly with `SUMX` instead

```
Total =
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        Table1[Client] = EARLIER( Table1[Client] )
    ),
    Table1[Sales]
)
```

---

Lots of ways to skin the cat.

Comment: First one worked. I gotta say, this "ALLEXCEPT" has me all confused. Seems to me like it would do the opposite.

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive at first, but you're basically specifying what you want to keep and removing everything else.

Comment: Great answer, thank you Alexis.

Comment: @AlexisOlson : FYI, I stil refer to this post each time I need to use calculate. The ALLEXCEPT is still confusing for me :)